# Quais são os benefícios da programação em pares?

Tags: metodologia, metodologia-ágil

A programação quase sempre foi feita por uma pessoa, que cria, analisa, testa e compila o código, tudo sozinho. Até um momento que surgiu **a programação em pares**, que dizia que programar em duplas era mais eficaz, mais rápido e gastava menos recursos do que uma programação "solitária".

Essa prática é amplamente usada pela **metodologia ágil XP** (e**X**treme **P**rogramming). Quais são os benefícios em ter alguém ao seu lado enquanto você programa? Isso realmente irá deixar o trabalho mais rápido?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

O resumo do benefício costuma ser:

## Duas cabeças pensam melhor que uma.

Em problemas complicados pode haver vantagem, principalmente se usado pontualmente. As pessoas não ficam empacadas demais em algo, mas também pode ocorrer de não só uma, mas duas pessoas ficarem empacadas.

Há uma espécie de *code review* automático. Mas alguns questionam isto. Há quem diga que tem menos erros, mas falta comprovação que isso ocorra de forma mais intensa que outras técnicas. Pode até acontecer mas com um custo alto.

Alguns dizem que o código pode ficar melhor porque tem alguém criticando ali na hora, mas isso depende muito de quem está do lado, e pode trazer conflitos quando isto ocorre.

Algumas pessoas costumam dizer que é mais eficiente assim, mas nunca vi comprovação. Pode haver alguns casos que um problema que uma das pessoas está com dificuldade e a outra enxerga um caminho mais facilmente, mas precisa ser muito ganho para compensar porque são duas pessoas fazendo um trabalho só.

Pode ser interessante como forma de treinamento de um programador menos experiente, mas efetivamente elimina as vantagens que são ditas como existentes nessa modalidade. Pode servir também como avaliação de funcionários acompanhando o processo de cada um, mas tem gente que não rende bem quando estão sendo monitoradas.

Pode ser interessante mais de uma pessoa no time entender o processo que foi usado para chegar naquele código, mas pode ser um *band aid* em algo errado no time.

É mais difícil procrastinar. E pode manter o moral alto, mas também pode ocorrer o contrário. Quando você envolve psicologia técnicas podem ser problema, ignoram as necessidades das pessoas.

Algumas pessoas tendem dizer que possuem outras vantagens mais difíceis ainda de medir e que não são técnicas. Você pode integrar melhor socialmente o time, mas pode gerar conflitos.

Existem desvantagens, a mais óbvia é que duas pessoas estão fazendo o mesmo trabalho, é meio que um trocando a lâmpada e o outro olhando ou falando pra não esquecer de rosquear direito. Muitas das desvantagens que costumam ser colocadas no fundo podem ser desvantagens ou pelo menos gerar uma desvantagem por causa daquilo.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).